# htaccess to mimic subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal-7

For the developement site i have a subdomian named dev, *dev.mysite.com*

Now i want to mimic a subdomain for this. The term subdomain might be ambiguous since i already got one. I would like to have the url like

1. **xxxx**.dev.mysite.com/node/23
2. **yyyy**.dev.mysite.com/node/23
3. **erer**.dev.mysite.com/node/23
4. **anything**.dev.mysite.com/node/23

As you can see i would like to make the **Bold** section dynamic along with my subdomain. Is it possible? How to do that if yes.

Comment: What do you mean by "mimic a subdomain"? Where do you want those URLs to map to? The same place as `mysite.com/node/`?

Comment: @JonLin yes to same node/*

Comment: Just add ServerAliases for all of your subdomains in the vhost config of your main domain.

Comment: How to do that ? Cant i add it in local ? What if i dont have root access ?

Comment: @JonLin i dont think all subdomain ServerAliases will work, since i already have my dev site as a subdomain. What you think ??